# Quicken resource fork issue? Identical files behaving differently (one works, one doesn't)

Tags: macos, unix, data-recovery, file-types, quicken

My hard drive recently crashed, and my last Time Machine backup was in November.  Fortunately, I was able to get all the data successfully recovered, however, I'm having a serious issue opening my Quicken Backup Files, which contain a lot of my important financial records.

The recovered drive contains all of the Quicken Backup Data files (*.qdfm) which were missing, but none of them are recognized by Quicken and all return an "Unable to Open File" error.

The Quicken forums suggest that this may be a resource fork issue, and that in transferring over from the data recovery company, the resource forks were stripped from the file.  I had them also send me a zipped folder of the files, which should work around the resource fork issue, but that still didn't work.

In trying to figure this out, I took some old backups from my Time Machine and compared them with the same exact file from the same date that was recovered from my drive.  The old files (from Time Machine) work fine and restore in Quicken, while the new files don't.

I even compared them on a HEX level using Beyond Compare, and they are all identical:

[image: Screenshot from Beyond Compare]

When viewing them in Finder, the OS doesn't seem to recognize the file types, instead show Unix files, and I'm wondering if that might be the issue.  Also, it shows different file sizes that don't show up when comparing in Beyond Compare (see the Data File and Data File Alias sizes)

[image: Finder windows comparing files]

The data is in the Data File, and I know it's there because I can see snippets of text from my entries within the HEX editor, but not enough to piece it together.

I also tried using TypeShuffler to re-identify the file types, which worked for changing the icon, but didn't change the outcome.

Does anyone know if there is a reason that the file types and sizes are different in Finder but not in Beyond Compare?  Are there parts of a file that won't show up in a HEX editor, that could perhaps be different and/or missing?  Where does the "file kind" information reside?

My hope is that since the body of the DATA FILE seems intact and present, that if I can figure out how to make it understand the files, maybe by fixing the resource forks, or copying over the missing sections or headers from a "good" file, that I can hopefully get it to open.

Comment: Are the backups possibly from a different version of the program?

Comment: How can `Beyond Compare` say that a 0 bytes file is equal to a 408 bytes file.  It sounds like whatever you recovered actually wasn't **fully** recovered.

Comment: Within Beyond Compare, it's showing that both of those files are 0 bytes.  I how it is that Beyond Compare thinks a file is 0 bytes, while Finder thinks it to be 408 bytes?  What part of the file is Beyond Compare not seeing, and is there another way I could possibly view it?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's having a similar issue, I figured out a solution!

In terminal, I compared the file size of the two files, and they still matched.  However, I found the command to compare the sizes of their resource forks, which did NOT match.  The resource fork on my "bad" file was zero, while the resource fork on the new file was 20662. So I copied the resource fork from a new Quicken Data File to the old Data File using:

```
cp QuickenDataFileNew/..namedfork/rsrc QuickenDataFileOld/..namedfork/rsrc"
```

Then I changed the Creator Code to INTU (Quicken 2007) and the file type to BDAT (Quicken Data File) and it worked!